# ng-Include inside a ng-include,both tied to different controllers

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a ng-include which points to a child.html which is tied to childcontroller and the parent.html file is tied to parentcontroller and inside child.html file there is another ng-include which points to a grandChild.html which is tied to grandchildcontroller. The problem is grandchild.html does not recognize grandchildcontroller.

The console error on chrome is

> angular.js:15567 TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
>
> ```
> at grandchildcontroller(core.js:18)
> at Object.invoke (angular.js:5141)
> at $controllerInit (angular.js:11704)
> at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:10517)
> at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:9832)
> at publicLinkFn (angular.js:9697)
> at Object.link (angular.js:29821)
> at angular.js:1388
> at invokeLinkFn (angular.js:11266)
> at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:10585)
> "<div ng-include="'...../grandChild.html'" class="ng-scope" data-ng-animate="1">"
> ```

I tried following.....

try 1.  put `<div ng-controller="childcontroller as vm">` in child.html
    and `<div ng-controller="grandchildcontroller as vm">` in grandchildcontroller.html

The error I get is

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $modalInstanceProvider <- $modalInstance <- childcontroller <- childcontroller
>
> ```
> at angular.js:138
> at angular.js:4924
> at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:5084)
> at angular.js:4929
> at getService (angular.js:5084)
> at injectionArgs (angular.js:5109)
> at Object.invoke (angular.js:5133)
> at $controllerInit (angular.js:11704)
> at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:10517)
> at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:9832)
> "<div class="modal-content" modal-transclude="">"
> ```

try 2.           `<div ng-controller ="childcontroller as vm" ng-include="'......./child.html'"></div>`  in parent.html.   I get same error as try 1 is getting.

Comment: Can you share a sample code? From the error message looks like the `childcontroller` is missing the injection of `$modalInstance`.

Comment: can you share the childcontroller code ?

Comment: completely changed everything not even using same code , so i don't know should i close this question because what i did is not solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

Assign different instance names to the each controller in the hierarchy:

```
<div ng-controller="childcontroller as vm1"> 
    <div ng-controller="grandchildcontroller as vm2"> 

         <input ng-model="vm1.child">

         <input ng-model="vm2.grandchild">

    </div>
</div>
```

This makes the template clearer and avoids potential data hiding problems.

Comment: Tried above , didn't work. Thanks for idea. I was hopeful